# Import SQL dump to PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I have 5GB SQL dump and I want to import that to Postgres. I have one problem in SQL dump that is `CREATE TABLE IF EXISTS`. This is invalid in Postgres. I am unable to remove this line from that dump because that is huge in SIZE (5GB).

I am doing all these in Google Cloud. If there is any way to migrate from Google SQL to Postgres that will also work for me.

Comment: What kind of dump is that? How did you create it? Btw: `create table if exists` makes no sense whatsoever. Did you mean `if NOT exists`?

Comment: Are you trying to import a mysql dump into postgres? If so, the `create if not exists` is just one of many problems you will have

Comment: @JorgeCampos: `create table if NOT exists` **is** supported by Postgres. But not `create table if exists` (which doesn't make sense to begin with and wouldn't actually work)

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting), you can export your data to a PostgreSQL dump using the `pg_dump` command. Command:
`pg_dump -U [USERNAME] --format=plain --no-owner --no-acl [DATABASE_NAME] | sed -E 's/(DROP|CREATE|COMMENT ON) EXTENSION/-- \1 EXTENSION/g' > [SQL_FILE].sql`